# Atrix 4G App Development

Tags: android

I am soon getting an Android phone, that I'll then be hobby-developing random little apps for.  (I know that its not best practice to use my main phone for development, but I'm going to anyway :P).

My main question is this:  I have been looking at the Atrix 4G, and will have it through AT&T.  Across the internet I came across a few things saying how AT&T is a pain that they only let you download apps through their app/store etc.  I've ready about this 'sideloading' thing that I assume I'll have to use to load my own apps and all too.  Bottom line, will I have a problem loading my own apps with an Atrix 4G & AT&T combo?

Thanks
-Will

Comment: Even if you have the old sw that doesn't allow 3rd party apps, this restriction doesn't apply to apps installed over ADB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They actually let that limitation go. Finally...

http://www.engadget.com/2011/05/17/atandt-sideloading-officially-a-go-designed-to-allow-amazon-appst/